# Find nearest X,Y coordinate within another list of coordinates in R

Tags: r, distance

I have a data.frame that contains the location tag of animals in x and y coordinates. This is as follows:

```
> head(Coords)
  Tag Animal       X       Y
1     228      1 -18.226  26.720
2     232      2 -18.268   7.558
3     233      3 -18.274  -2.041
4     307      4  -7.975 -61.421
5     241      5   8.052 -61.364
6     243      6  18.196  -2.118
```

I now wish to calculate the minimum distance between each animal's location and the nearest coordinates in another data.frame. An example of this below:

```
> head(OutsideLines, 10)
        X     Y
1  -15.22 19.11
2  -15.12 19.11
3  -15.02 19.11
4  -14.92 19.11
5  -14.82 19.11
6  -14.72 19.11
7  -14.62 19.11
8  -14.52 19.11
9  -14.42 19.11
10 -14.32 19.11
```

Is there a way to do this quickly and efficiently in R?

Comment: have you tried the [dist](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/proxy/versions/0.4-17/topics/dist) function? assuming you need `euclidean` distance here.

Comment: If you need geographic distances you might consider `rgeos::gDistance()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the actual distance formula, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)

Coords %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(min_dist = min(sqrt((X - OutsideLines$X) ^ 2 + (Y - OutsideLines$Y) ^ 2)))

#> Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>     Tag Animal       X       Y  min_dist
#>   <int>  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1   228      1 -18.226  26.720  8.182184
#> 2   232      2 -18.268   7.558 11.947343
#> 3   233      3 -18.274  -2.041 21.370347
#> 4   307      4  -7.975 -61.421 80.780573
#> 5   241      5   8.052 -61.364 83.525871
#> 6   243      6  18.196  -2.118 38.831923
```